# Is it possible to change the model being used on ng-model through ng-change?

Tags: angularjs

I have a select element where the model is an attribute of a class. the class has attributes A and B.

```
<select ng-model="A" ng-options="x.CustomerId as x.Name for x in options.tableData.childCustomers"></select>
```

in the options, there's 1 option that is a specific id (let's say -1) while the others are 0 and above. if -1 is selected, I want the attribute B to be used as the model instead of A. is this possible to change in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat.

You can assign a value to B, but A will still exist normally.
You can put an ng-change by calling a function and checking the value of A, if A == -1 then B = something else B = ''.

Example:

add to html element(select):

```
 ng-change="verifyValue()"
```

In AngularJS

```
$scope.verifyValue = function() {
    $scope.B = '';
    $scope.B = $scope.A == '-1'?'Negative Value':'';
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response! I've kind of update my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70190457/change-dynamic-name-of-ng-model. the problem is actually I have ng-model="ROW.A" or "ROW.B", where row is the selected class in a list of classes since this will be for a drop down. therefore I'm trying to dynamically change it within the html and not the controller if possible.