# Change dynamic name of ng-model

Tags: angularjs, ngmodel

I have a select element where the model is an attribute of a class. the class has attributes A and B. childCustomers has the attributes Id, Name, and Attribute. Attribute has either the value of A or B. Right now, it looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="row.A" ng-options="x.CustomerId as x.Name for x in options.tableData.childCustomers"></select>
```

I want to be able to change the model to be either "row.A" or "row.B" depending on what option is selected. I've tried using [] like `ng-model="row.[x.Attribute]"` and {{}} like `ng-model="row.{{x.Attribute}}"` but that doesn't seem right. Any ideas?

Comment: this seems to be an angularJS question, not Angular? Please correct the tags if that is the case.

Comment: @AT82 thanks for the correction!